# Why is Flutter saying Unidentified name "context"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Flutter says that context is undefined in the 2nd last line of the following code:

```
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
    child: TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: title == "Clock" ? Colors.red: Colors.transparent),
      onPressed: () {
        var menuInfo = Provider.of<MenuInfo>(context);
      },
```

But, I already have defined context in my main.dart as follows:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider<MenuInfo>(
          create: (context) => MenuInfo(MenuType.clock, "null", "null"),
          child: HomePage()),
    );
```

Why is Flutter saying that I have not defined context?

Comment: where did you place the `return Padding` ?
you can have `context`  inside `StatelessWidget` or `StatefullWidget`

Comment: @pmatatias return Padding is outside StatelessWidget. How to access Context now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This problem has been solved.
If creating a function or widget outside a class that extends stateless or stateful widgets, BuildContext must be passed in as a parameter during declaration as shown here:

```
Widget BuildButton(String title, String img, BuildContext context) {

  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
    child: TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: title == "Clock" ? Colors.red: Colors.transparent),
      onPressed: () {
        var menuInfo = Provider.of<MenuInfo>(context);
      },
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(img, scale: 1.5,),
          SizedBox(height: 6),
          Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'avenir',color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
          ),
        ]
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you place the padding thing code outside build. So, in this case you will need to parse context too in your parameter.

```
MenuInfo(MenuType.clock, "null", "null", context)


Widget MenuInfo(...., BuildContex context) {
    return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
    child: TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: title == "Clock" ? Colors.red: 
    Colors.transparent),
      onPressed: () {
        var menuInfo = Provider.of<MenuInfo>(context);
      },
    ... }
```

Comment: Yup, you're right! thanks so much!